# Image not saving on local storage from firebase and not able to see on gallery

Tags: android, firebase, picasso

I am using Picasso to load images from firebase db.
Now I want to save it on local storage.
But it's not working. I have tried other posts on StackOverflow but none of them worked fine.
Some of them having runtime permission issue.P lease help.
So I need to save the image in local storage so that user can find it on gallery and it should be visible in the gallery
I have added permission for reading/ writing on the external device

> Code not working, not saving the image on local storage though its saying image is saved, Not able to see in the gallery

```
public class SingleImageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String imageurl;
    ImageView img;
    Button download,share;
    private Target target;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_single_image);
        imageurl = getIntent().getStringExtra("imageurl");
         img=findViewById(R.id.image);
         download=findViewById(R.id.download);
         share=findViewById(R.id.share);

        Picasso
                .with(getApplicationContext())
                .load(imageurl)
                .into(img);


        download.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Download Started...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                boolean success = true;
                File wallpaperDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+File.separator+"Walls");
                if(!wallpaperDirectory.exists()){
                    success = wallpaperDirectory.mkdir();
                }
                if (success) {
                    downloadImg();
                    download.setEnabled(!download.isEnabled());
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "The app was not allowed to write to your storage. Please consider granting it this permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });

         share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {

             }
         });
         }
    private void downloadImg() {
        target = new Target() {
            @Override
            public void onBitmapLoaded(final Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        String filename = "img"+ new Date().getTime() + ".png";

                        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/Walls"+File.separator, filename);
                        try {
                            file.createNewFile();
                            FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100,ostream);
                            ostream.close();
                        }
                        catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }).start();

            }

            @Override
            public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {}

            @Override
            public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {}
        };

        Picasso
                .with(getApplicationContext())
                .load(imageurl)
                .into(target);

    }



}
```

Comment: How is your code not working? Does it compile? Does it run? Does it crash? What errors are you getting?

Comment: The image which is being saved not shown in the gallery.
And I have to add storage permission manually from app settings.
Though it's saying that image is saved but not able to see the image where it's saved

Comment: any error ?...........

Comment: like fileNotfound IO exeption

Comment: did u getted run time permission ?

Comment: @Ashvinsolanki no error but image is not saving

Comment: did u taking run time storage rea and write permision @farhan

Comment: yes, the issue is solved, finally. I need to make a helper class to save the image